# cURL in php not working

Tags: php, curl, https, xampp

i am not able to fetch the web page content of Google search page, but when i am using curl to get info from an API, it is working fine. i want to get Google page content so later on i can manually extract links from that page. i have tried many times, but unable to get web page content from any URL. Presently, i am working with XAMPP software to run PHP codes.

i am using curl_exec() command. http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php
 is the source link for the code i tried.

Please also tell me how to use https:// in xampp software using curl command in php

Comment: Try to get more information about the curl request by using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // For HTTPS
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); // For HTTPS
$response=curl_exec($ch);
echo $response; // Google's HTML source will be printed
curl_close($ch);
```

The reason why you were not able to get the source is you were not using the  **`CURLOPT_URL`** parameter instead it was **`CURLOPT_FILE`**.

Comment: i have added something in my question...plzz do reply....how can i use https:// in xampp s/w using curl in php.

Comment: You have to edit the PHP.ini file in your XAMPP software to allow the php to use curl library.
Simply open your php.ini file, search for "curl" keyword.
There must be a semicolon in the extension. Just remove the semicolon (;) and save the .ini file. And then restart XAMPP.
Chagne line 
;extension=php_curl.dll
to 
extension=php_curl.dll

Comment: @user2976610, Try the new code. I have added two parameters For HTTPS.